# How to encode colors for windows console

Tags: mercurial

I try to setup a template for my mercurial (version 2.4.2+20130203) logs. Tried the following template:

```
lg = glog --template "\033[31m({rev})  {node|short}\033[0m \x1b[35m [{branch}] \033[1;34m<{author|person}>\033[0m \033[32m({date|age})\033[0m \n\t\t{desc}\n\033[0m"
```

It works fine with `color.mode` set to `ansi`. But then standard `hg status` does not show any colors but mess instead:

```
←[0;35;1;4m? patch.patch←[0m
```

When I change `color.mode`  to `win32` `hg status` works well, but `hg lg` displays tree without any colors (and without `←[0;` mess).

Another weird thing is that when I use the same template as default via `ui.logtemplate` it is rendered with mess while `hg lg` renders colors.

Also tried setting TERM to empty string -- no result.

How should colors be specified for `win32` color mode?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the mode set to `win32`, and the above all worked fine, both on the command line and via an alias. Setting the mode to ansi messed everything up, but then I don't have an ansi driver. A look the source for the `color` extension shows that, in win32-mode, it tries to translate the ansi codes to a series of attributes and apply them using the [win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: what version of windows do you use?

Comment: I'm on standard WinXP at the moment - not tried it on my other box yet (Vista).

Comment: Thanks, I am on Windows 8 :)